# Finding a logic to map the values of two .tsv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, metadata

I am working on a problem where I have 2 .tsv files and one has been arranged wrongly with respect to the other one.
When I scan the file , I noticed a pattern which I am unable to put it in terms of coding language. The pattern that I observed was :

> For every increase in the row number of metadata file = 8 rows of increment to match in the flipped_metadata.tsv file to match the same values in the metadata file
> For every increase in the flipped_metadata file = 12 rows if increment in the metadata.tsv file to match the same values in the flipped_metadata file.

For more clarity I have attached the 2 .tsv files along with this:
[Metadata.tsv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cs_2U7LFATxT0w-EkXw_NAGE_xrKmF47/view) and [Flipped_metadata.tsv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ajqFPmBMjNEtGfm9zuDQafmQlc_mp3Xg/view)

Comment: What is your question? i.e. what would be your expected output?

Comment: The expected output would be in row-major instead of column-major format. It should look something like  A1,B1,C1,D1...H1  and then A2,B2,C2,D2,...H2 , so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#module-openpyxl.utils.cell) library has good functions for dealing with Excel cell locations. These can be used to convert `A1` to a proper row and column.

1. Read each row in and convert the cell reference to a simple numeric row and column value. Use a dictionary to store each cell found with the two values for that cell. e.g. `cells[(1,1)] = "123 456"`
2. Whilst reading in, keep a track of the largest row and column.
3. Create an empty array (list of lists) to allow each cell to be assigned into.
4. Iterate over all of the dictionary items and assign each value into the array.
5. Finally save the array to a new CSV file.

For example:

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
import csv

def flip(input_filename, output_filename):
    cells = {}
    max_row = 0
    max_col = 0

    with open(input_filename) as f_input:
        for cell, v1, v2 in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t'):
            col_letter, row_number = coordinate_from_string(cell)
            col_number = column_index_from_string(col_letter)
            cells[(row_number, col_number)] = f"{v1} {v2}"
            
            if row_number > max_row:
                max_row = row_number
                
            if col_number > max_col:
                max_col = col_number
                
    output = [[''] * max_col for _ in range(max_row)]
            
    for (row_number, col_number), values in cells.items():
        output[row_number-1][col_number-1] = values

    with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        csv.writer(f_output).writerows(output)

flip('metadata.tsv', 'output_metadata.csv')    
flip('flipped_metadata.tsv', 'output_flipped_metadata.csv')
```

This would give you:

[image: Flipped data screenshot]

Note: this approach correctly handles all cell references e.g. `FK42`. It would also handle holes in the data, if `A2` was deleted it would still align correctly, as it is not 100% clear if data in cells can be missing,